# Jetpack Infinite Scroll (loading single post without content)

Tags: wordpress, scroll, infinite, jetpack

I'm trying to just load additional posts in Wordpress, nothing major, in a custom theme. The functionality is working per say, but it's loading from the beginning of the loop again, ignoring the fact that the ones it's now loading are already loaded. Also, it's only loading one post - the first in the loop.

In addition, it's only loading the title of the post, ignoring the template (which they're both loaded from), which also includes the post thumbnail and the excerpt.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
add_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll', array(
    'type'           => 'click',
    'footer_widgets' => false,
    'container'      => 'feeder',
    'wrapper'        => false,
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'footer' => false,
    'render'         => 'news_infinite_scroll_render'
) );

function news_infinite_scroll_render() {
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/news-posts-list', get_post_format() 
);
}
```

And the template is

```
<div <?php post_class('column column-block'); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <article>
    <a href="<?php echo the_permalink();?>" target="_blank"><?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/featured-image-news-list' ); ?></a>
        <header>
        <table class="post-details">
            <tr>
                <td><a href="<?php echo the_permalink();?>" target="_blank"><?php the_title('<h5>', '</h5>');?></a></td>
                <td><small><?php the_time('j M Y') ?></small></td>
        </table>
        </header>
        <div class="entry-content">
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

*** Edit

Okay, I've got it loading multiple posts (I hadn't incorporated a `while` function in the template, but it's still loading from the start of the loop again, and still only loading the title, not the image or excerpt.

*** Edit 2

And I've now got the posts loading correctly (removed the custom loop and just put a standard loop in). So now, I'm just stuck with it not loading the post thumbnail - everything else is working fine.

*** Edit 3

And so I've worked out it's related to Foundation Interchange. Any help on getting that to fire correctly would be appreciated.